# Extract an image from a video hosted on a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to extract an image/thumbnail from a video hosted on some website. For exemple, the host could be youtube.com or whatever.com and i want to extract an image for a precise frame, i.e 2:12.

I have the direct URL for the video. I searched and found how to do it for youtube or vimeo, they provide xml or json with a path to the thumbnail. However i can't find how to do it for a web site that doesn't provide those informations.

Ive downloaded FFmpeg, but it doesn't seem to offer to extract an image from a video hosted on some web site.

Any other tool or any idea to make a tool myself ?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the Video Hosting website, maybe me or someone else can check it out and help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to do this on server side, and as far as I know you then need to transfer the video over to the server and run ffmpeg, as you already suggested.